# k'riah at the funeral of an adoptive parent

Tags: clothing, mourning-aveilus, kerovim-close-relatives

Should an adoptee of Jewish parentage do k'riah at the funeral of an adoptive parent, and, if so, should it be done on the left side of the garment or the right?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I'd be saddened to hear that this is applicable to you. You might want to take a look at [this closely related question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22803/5323), as well as [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36759/5323). You might also want to consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Also, you should probably seek the advice of a rabbi you know and trust, if this information will be actionable; we [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) around here. You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info.

Answer (score 2):

[Shvilim B'Daiya - page 48](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51729&st=&pgnum=50) says there is no obligation to tear Kriya for a stepparent. However one may do so if they want to. He does not indicate on which side it should be done, however being that it is not an obligation, I would say it should be done on the right side like a regular Aveil.

Comment: do you have a source that a normal avel rips on the right side?

Comment: @mevaqesh: See end of page http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51729&st=&pgnum=48

Comment: But that very source writes that for one's parents one rips on the left!

Comment: @mevaqesh: As I said "He does not indicate on which side it should be done for a stepparent, however being that it is not an obligation, I would say it should be done on the right side like a regular Aveil."

Comment: If it isn't an obligation, and merely mimics that of a relative, a case could definitely be made that the relative being mimicked is a parent for whom the ripping is performed on the left side.

Comment: @mevaqesh: You can write your own opposing answer. I stand by my contention.